# select data from one column based on another column's condition in the same table and insert that resulting data to another table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, reactjs

I have two tables recipemaster and ingredientmaster.

### recipemaster table

```
recipe_code |recipe_title |
------------|-------------|
1           |    one      |
2           |    two      |
3           |    three    |
4           |    four     |
```

### ingredientmaster table

```
ingredient_code |recipe_code |ingredient_detail |
----------------|------------|------------------|
                |            |                  |
```

In front end react, i am entering ingredient_detail based on the selected recipe_title from the recipemaster table using select box, what my question is, i need a query where i select recipe_title from recipemaster table and that should select the particular recipe_code based on the recipe_title and populate that particular recipe_code in the ingredientmaster table. Ofcourse ingredient_detail is also entered together. 
Ingredient_code is auto incremented, so no need to worry about that.. Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: minimal code example is needed

Comment: u mean u need front end react code?

Comment: i need just a postgresql query to put it on nodejs file where api calls are called from react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an `INSERT INTO..SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO ingredientmaster (recipe_code, ingredient_detail)
   SELECT recipe_code, 'TABLE SALT' ingredient_detail
     FROM recipemaster
    WHERE recipe_title = ?;
```

Comment: may i know what is that 'TABLE SALT' ?

Comment: @karthikshankar :  You said "Off course ingredient_detail is also entered together" in the question. So, It is just an example I gave you, which you would be passing from your js. I hope you know how to do it coz I don't know node.js

Comment: y do you select ingredient_detail from recipemaster when there is no column like this.

Comment: @karthikshankar : In sql, you need not always select the column that is available in the table. You may select any  value  and use an alias to represent it as a column. Have you tried to implement this in your code? Are you facing any issue?

Comment: Thank you @Kaushik, it works as i expected, i executed in the database and it works. Now i should populate it with nodejs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166025/discussion-between-karthik-shankar-and-kaushik-nayak).